# how to set the value of len(list_name)...?

Tags: python, list

I  have  a  list  that  might  return  null values,  then  I  have  to  iterate  through  it...ex:

for iter_aeh  in  range(len(alert_event_history_rows)):

alert_event_history_rows  is  a  list  and  it  can  be  null,  so  I  want  to  set  len(alert_event_history_rows) =  1  if alert_event_history_rows  is  a  list  of  null values(0  rows).

But  I  get  following  error:

**SyntaxError: can't assign to function call**

```
for record_ae  in  alert_event_rows:
        if  len(alert_event_history_rows)  ==  0:
        len(alert_event_history_rows)  =  1
            for iter_aeh  in  range(len(alert_event_history_rows)):
```

How  to  set  the  value  of  len(alert_event_history_rows)...?

Comment: Add an element to alert_event_history_rows

Comment: Note:  `for n in range(len(container))` is rarely appropriate.  You usually need simply `for item in container`, and occasionally you want `for index, item in enumerate(container)`

Comment: Note2: `if  len(alert_event_history_rows)  ==  0:` would preferably be written `if not alert_event_history_rows`

Answer (score 1):

Don't.  Just handle the case where your list is empty with logic:

```
if alert_event_history_rows:
  for item in alert_event_history_rows:
    # do something
else:
  # alert_event_history_rows was an empty list..
  # do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error indeed:

```
len(alert_event_history_rows)  =  1
```

... because you cannot make an assignment to a function call on the left hand side. It must be a variable that can receive the value. If what you really want to do is reinitialize that list to a single element null list, then you might do:

```
alert_event_history_rows = [None]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem

```
for record_ae  in  alert_event_rows:
    for iter_aeh  in  range(max(len(alert_event_history_rows), 1)):
```